# Doors next generation custom attribute updater

Tags: rest, dng, oslc

Hi I'm a newbie working on a script in doors next generation project using rest APIs.

Requirement is to update the attributes inside a module and contents using script.

I am able to get till required module. Can anyone please guide me next steps and which rest apis to hit.